# TableView does not reloaddata when I clicked "More data..." at the last row of tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

Request my test webService for the data,

The tableView's last row is "More data..."

when click this row, send another request to get more data,

and I use [tableView reloaddata] many times, but there is nothing

happened, and I dont know why.So,please help me with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

and there is my tableViewController.h class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "NoticeDetailViewController.h"

@interface NoticeViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{    
    NSMutableArray *allNoticeArray;

    NSArray *addNoticeArray;

    NSInteger totalNotice;

    NSInteger pageIndex;

    UITableView *tableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allNoticeArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *addNoticeArray;
@property NSInteger totalNotice;
@property NSInteger pageIndex;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
- (NSMutableArray *)getNoticeList :(NSInteger)pageIndex;
@end
```

And tableViewController.m class:

```
#import "NoticeViewController.h"
#import "Notice.h"
#import "OAURLEncodingAdditions.h"
@interface NoticeViewController ()
@end

@implementation NoticeViewController
@synthesize allNoticeArray;
@synthesize addNoticeArray;
@synthesize pageIndex;
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize totalNotice;

- (NSMutableArray *)getNoticeList :(NSInteger)pageIndex
    { 
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSString *userId = appDelegate.user.userId;
        NSString *departmentId = appDelegate.user.departmentId;

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/FMS/Pages/Service/FMService.svc/GetAnnouncement?userId=%@&departmentId=%@&pageIndex=%d&pageSize=%d",userId,departmentId,self.pageIndex,1]];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
        [request startSynchronous];
        NSError *error = [request error];
        if (!error) 
        {
            NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
            NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
            NSArray *noticeArray = [responseDict objectForKey:@"d"];

            NSMutableArray *arrayOfAllNotice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (NSDictionary *noticeDic in noticeArray) 
            {
                NSString *body = [noticeDic objectForKey:@"Body"];
                NSString *departmentName = [noticeDic objectForKey:@"DepartmentName"];
                NSString *noticeId = [noticeDic objectForKey:@"Id"];
                NSString *isTop = [noticeDic objectForKey:@"IsTop"];
                NSString *readState = [noticeDic objectForKey:@"ReadState"];
                NSString *realName = [noticeDic objectForKey:@"RealName"];
                NSString *title = [noticeDic objectForKey:@"Title"];

                int noid = [noticeId intValue];
                int isto = [isTop intValue];
                int read = [readState intValue];

                Notice *notice = [[Notice alloc] initWithBody:body 
                                       departmentName:departmentName 
                                             noticeId: noid 
                                                isTop:isto 
                                            readState:read 
                                             realName:realName 
                                                title:title];
                [arrayOfAllNotice addObject:notice];
            }
        self.addNoticeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayOfAllNotice];
    }
    else
    {
       ....
    }
    [allNoticeArray addObjectsFromArray:addNoticeArray];    
    NSLog(@"allNoticeArray count: %d",[allNoticeArray count]);  //Here:When the last row clicked, the number changes:1->2  
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    return allNoticeArray;
}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger theNumberOfRowsInSection;

    if ( [allNoticeArray count] < (self.totalNotice)) 
    {
        theNumberOfRowsInSection = [allNoticeArray count]+1;
    }
    if ( [allNoticeArray count] == (self.totalNotice)) 
    {
        theNumberOfRowsInSection = [allNoticeArray count];
    }

    return theNumberOfRowsInSection; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    static NSString *NoticeListTableIdentifier = @"NoticeListTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NoticeListTableIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:NoticeListTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ( [allNoticeArray count] < (self.totalNotice) ) 
    {
        if ( [indexPath row] != [allNoticeArray count]) 
        {
            NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
            Notice *noticeOfTheRow = [allNoticeArray objectAtIndex:row];
            NSString *title = noticeOfTheRow.title;
            cell.textLabel.text = title;
        }
        else 
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"More...";
        }
    }
    if ( [allNoticeArray count] == (self.totalNotice) ) 
    {
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        Notice *noticeOfTheRow = [allNoticeArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSString *title = noticeOfTheRow.title;
        cell.textLabel.text = title;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( [indexPath row] != [allNoticeArray count]) 
    {        
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];       
        Notice *notice = [allNoticeArray objectAtIndex:row];        
        NSString *noticeDetailTitle = notice.title;        
        NoticeDetailViewController *noticeDetailViewController = [[[NoticeDetailViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        noticeDetailViewController.title = noticeDetailTitle;        
        ticeDetailViewController.noticeIdForGet = notice.noticeId;        
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:noticeDetailViewController animated:YES];        
    }
    if ( [indexPath row] == [allNoticeArray count]) 
    {        
        MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        hud.labelText = @"reload...";        
        self.pageIndex ++;        
        [self getNoticeList:self.pageIndex];        
        [self.tableView reloadData];        
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];        
    }
}

- (void)pushBack
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    self.allNoticeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.pageIndex = 1;    
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"reload...";    
    self.title = @"Notice";    
    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" 
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                      target:self 
                                                                      action:@selector(pushBack)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;


    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"reload" 
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                     target:self 
                                                                     action:@selector(reloadNotice)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
    self.allNoticeArray = [self getNoticeList:self.pageIndex];    
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
 }
@end
```

Comment: œJxdev sorry this is alot of code. Can you tell us if numberOfRowsInSection returns the correct number of rows in a section after you called your "more data..."? It looks like there is a case in which it returns the uninitialized `theNumberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: NSLog(@"theNumberOfRowsInsection:%d",theNumberOfRowsInSection) after I called the "more data",and the number doesn't change

Comment: Do you update your `allNoticeArray` after doing the "More Data..."? I think your model is not up to date to reflect the changes in your tableView.

Comment: .... I am so sorry, I just forget connect the File's Owner to the IBOutlet tableView in .xib file! That's the reason of reloaddata doesn't work!I am such a idiot.OLO ! Thank you ! NickWeaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
if ( [indexPath row] == [allNoticeArray count])
```

to:

```
if ( [indexPath row] == [allNoticeArray count]-1)
```

The reason is that array (and row) indexing are base 0. So if an array has, say 3 objects, last object's index is 2

Comment: "theNumberOfRowsInSection = [allNoticeArray count]+1"; if there is more data,I +1 row in the theNumberOfRowsInSection function.Only there is no data to get, "theNumberOfRowsInSection = [allNoticeArray count]" at then I dont need to get more data

Comment: I made a such stupid mistake! Also, thank you!LOL, have a good day, Alladinian.

Answer (score 0):

BTW，with the new language features, there's no need to declare the ivars in the interface. The compiler will take care of them if you have already declared the properties and synthesized them.

```
@interface NoticeViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{    
    NSMutableArray *allNoticeArray;

    NSArray *addNoticeArray;

    NSInteger totalNotice;

    NSInteger pageIndex;

    UITableView *tableView;
}
//...
@end
```